# View with editable-fields and field-collection fields

Tags: views, users, entities

I have created a view of profile2 data, somekind like a extended user profile where users can add some personal data and other information of interest. I chose the view because in a next step of development I want to provide a profile search function. Basically I think to choose a View is the right way to go.

So when I (as a owner of a profile) call the view page (filter is set to my login UID, setup as a contextual filter) it shows up and the editable defined fields are all editable (by click). I wanted to provide a profile page view that is in-page editable (eg. functions as a form and a view, all in one). All this works great. Also I can use that view to show to anonymous users (as a search result) the profile content (non editable of course).

My problem are 2 field-collections in that profile that shows (due to the editable setting "Formatter" in the View field definition) both the "**add**" link and also the "**edit this field**" of the "editable setting" of these very 2 fields. That is redundant. I seem not to be able to find any way to switch off the second "**edit this field**" link. If I set these field-collections to the "default" formatter (not editable), I also get no "**add**" link to add values to the field collections. This is the case if the user just created an account and the collections are empty.

Now my question, how can I remove the "**edit this field**" link generated by the "editable" functionality? It seems, that JS add these links and I can not remove them anyhow. Is there any way I can override these two fields and remove the link (but still leave these fields in editable state)? Some theme override I could use, or somewhere within the fields template?

I played a little and defined a field template (named by the collection-field such as **views-view-field--field-work-experience.tpl.php**) and tried to remove the 'edit this link" or JS selector. If I now choose the formatter **editable-link**, (not the **editable** formatter) and change the code in the field template to

```
$markup = $row->field_field_work_experience[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
print $markup;
```

the "edit this field" from the editable-link module will not show up, but I get the wanted "add" link. The regular field template output

```
print $output;
```

will show both, the "add" link and the "edit this field" link.

Well, the first snippet is a dirty hack and a try and it might lead to undefined behavior. I do not like to keep up with that at all.

BTW, I have both modules installed, "editable-link" and "editable". I develop with drupal 7.

So is there any way I can remove these "editable field" links from the field-collection fields and just get the regular link "add".

I hope I described my problem clear enough, if not please let me know I try to explain more precisely.

Any help is greatly appreciated.